# does isset php function checks string length

Tags: php, wordpress

in my website's registration form, the following php code controls user first name field :

```
if (!isset($value[4])){
    $return = $register_msg['_register_some_msg'];
}
```

what does this code do ? does it have anything with **checking the string length** ?
currently it forces the first name of minimum 3 characters, but as i searched seems that `strlen()` Function checks the length of string which doesn't exists there.

Comment: A bit more code would be useful at least to identify where `$value` actually gets set

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAIK `isset` only checks if a variable name exists in memory and has some value to go with it. It doesn't check for anything else. If you put a boolean `false` in it, [it will still work](https://3v4l.org/ih87a) for example. **edit** question suddenly changed so this comment isn't valid anymore.

Comment: Yes, this is checking string length. Strings can have their individual characters accessed with array syntax, so this is checking to see if the `4`th position is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `isset()` method here just verify if `$value[4]` (your object, or string, or other) exists or not.

Comment: sorry i am new to php and  it is not clear for me yet. this code is part of indeed membership pro plugin for WordPress which simply controls what users enter in "first name" field in registration form.  $value is the string which users enter as their first name. as i mentioned because of this code, system accepts first names with 3 characters or more. delboy said "and you check if the 5th element is set" but the result is different.

Comment: A string can be wrote like an array of characters. For example : `$string= 'name';` $string[1] should return the 2nd element, so it returns the character  'a'. In your code, the method checks if the 5th elements is not empty, is a way to check if the length of your string is correct or not.

Comment: thanks for this great and easy to understand explanation, but seems it is a bad method to specify string length. can i simply remove this line of code and use strlen() function instead ? would there be any problem by removing that ? the only other code which exists for first name field is:
case 'first_name':
  if (!preg_match('/^[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]*$/u', $value)){
 $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_firstname_error_msg'];
}

Comment: i am using the latest version of "indeed membership pro" plugin and i wonder why they have used this bad isset() function to check string length, instead of using strlen() function in their code !!!!!

Comment: Actually, you can use strlen() method instead of isset() method. If you want to use strlen() in your project, use it as is : `if(strlen($value)>3){$return = $register_msg['_register_some_msg'];}`. Try it and say me if it works ;)

Comment: since i need to force minimum of 3 characters in first name, i used if(strlen($value)<3){$return = $register_msg['_register_some_msg'];}     
but strange result : plugin doesn't allow first names with one character, but allows those containing 2 characters !!!!  characters are entered with Arabic letters and i don't know whether it is relevant !

Comment: i noticed something. because Arabic letters are written sticked together for example "مرحبا"   , system consumes "مر"  as one character. but if i write " م ر " , system assumes it as two characters. any workaround for it ?

Comment: The method strlen() counts the characters, even the empty character (space). Otherwise, try to use `<=` instead of `<`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this code is checking string length.

It appears you have two arrays.

`$value` is a numerical array, and you check if the 5th element is set. (index starts on 0).

`$register_msg` is an associative array, instead of numbers as the index, it uses keys. Here you assign the value of key `_register_some_msg` to your return variable.

The other option is that `$value` is a string, and it's using bad practice to check each letter by referencing them as an array key:

```
<?php

$x = 'abcd';
echo $x[3];

//output: d
```

Which is just bad. use `strlen()` instead http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: `$value` is most likely a string and `!isset($value[4])` is a rudimentary way of checking string length.

Comment: omg that's disgusting lol, forgot about that insanely bad practice @castis, updating answer

Comment: Why is it bad practice? Sure it's not really readable and clear for someone who hasn't programmed in C, but why is it bad practice? Strings are just arrays of chars, so you should be able to access them with array syntax.

Comment: because it's not really readable as you say, and makes devs automatically assume (wrongly) that we are dealing with a real array. Just use `strlen()`!

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with checking this way. It's just confusing to the uninitiated is all.

Comment: @delboy1978uk fair enough. One of the downsides of compile-on-runtime-dynamically-typed languages I guess...

Comment: sorry i am new to php and it is not clear for me yet. 
the above code is a simple code which exists in "indeed membership pro" plugin for wordpress.  $value here means the string which user enters as his first name in registration form field.
because of that code, system doesn't accepts first names with 2 characters, but accepts first names with 3 characters or more.
i can't understand what does it have with this answer : 
" $value is a numerical array, and you check if the 5th element is set. "

Comment: @Loek: What does this program do? `$x = 'Štříngš äré jüst árraýs of chařš.';echo $x[7]` (Hint: not what you are expecting - in PHP they are arrays of *bytes*, and variable-width character encoding breaks your assumption.) https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: @delboy1978uk: I would suggest `mb_strlen()`, else the answer suffers from the same flaw as the OP's method.

Comment: @Piskvor I was thinking about that when I wrote my comment. Didn't have the time to check it. So thanks!